# Combining independent observables for the same quantity, how to check independence

Tags: chi-squared-test, dataset, independence

Let's assume we have a set of observations $\{x_i\}$ of a physical quantity $x$. We have a model $x=X(y)$, where $y$ is a free parameter. Let's assume that we have two distinct observables, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, that can be used to measure $y$ from the observations. If the two observables $f$ and $g$ are independent, then I can just use minimization of $\chi^2$ to combine the results and get an estimate for $y$.

For example: let's say that $\{x_i\}_1^N$ are drawn from a Gaussian population, then the mean, $\bar{x}=\Sigma_i \frac{x_i}{N}$, and the sample variance, $s^2=\Sigma_i\frac{(x_i - \hat{x})^2}{N-1}$, are two independent observables, that can be used to measure the parameters of the parent Gaussian distribution. On the other side, also $\Sigma_i x_i $ and $\Sigma_i x_i^2$  are independent, aren't they?

Another example: if I have a set of observations $\{x_i\}_i^N$ and I consider the mean on the first 60% of the data, and then I consider the mean of the last 60% of the data, these are two distinct observables for my data set. But they are not independent observables, because they use the same information about the data twice.

In principle the dataset could be more complicated, for example it may be constituted by a time series $x_i=x(t_i)$, and the observables could be Fourier transform and the other the probability density function of $x_i$.

The question is: how can I know if two observables are independent? Is there a way I can combine observables that are not independent?

Can anybody provide a good reference for this problem?

Comment: Please do not cross post. That is against SE policy. Decide where you want to ask this question & delete the other post.

Comment: OK, I can understand where this policy is coming from, and why you may not want to have the same questions on two different SEs. The idea would be there is a unique answer to a problem. But if you think about it, these two questions are not the same question, and the reason is they have been asked to two different audiences. This makes these questions distinct.

Comment: You can certainly ask two *related* questions on separate SE sites, where one focuses on aspects in physics & the other focuses on the statistical aspects. However, these questions look identical--just copied & pasted--to me.

Comment: as i said the difference is in the audience. anyway, it is ok. give me a couple of hours, I will paraphrase it

Comment: Of course asking identical questions on different SE sites is asking different audiences! I suspect the SE team is aware of that... Nonetheless, asking an identical question on multiple SE sites is against SE policy.

Comment: A question that is stated this abstractly needs to be utterly clear about the meanings of its terms.  In general a "physical model" involves no stochastic components, raising the question of the sense in which you mean "independent." What is the source of the implied randomness in your models? How exactly is the lack of independence being modeled? It isn't in the least apparent what your $\chi^2$ statistic is or how you would minimize it to estimate $y$--and indeed in many statistical settings that's not a good way to construct an estimator. Please edit your post to clarify these points.